# MYSQL finding duplicates within a minute of each other

Tags: mysql

My MySQL is not that good.

I am trying to search for duplicate entries in a table made within 5 minutes of each other. There are unique id's (autoincremental).

Basically, a number of incorrect duplicates have been made into the database, they have a different 'id' with a same 'field' value, all made within 5 minutes of each other.

When I run the command below, it comes back blank, but I know there are duplicates.

Any ideas why the below command will not work?

In the example below, 'id' is the autoincrement id value, 'table' is the name of the table, 'field' is the name of a field within the table and 'timestamp' is the timestamp of the entry.

Thanks.

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM table AS a CROSS JOIN table AS b
WHERE a.id != b.id 
    AND field = uniquevalue 
    AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, a.timestamp,b.timestamp) = -5;
```

UPDATE:
Based on the answer below I also tried this, but it still returns no entries:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM table AS a CROSS JOIN table AS b 
WHERE (a.id != b.id) AND ('field' = uniquevalue) 
AND abs(timestampdiff(MINUTE, a.timestamp, b.timestamp)) < 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for an absolute difference eg exactly 5 mins . You want 
to change your where to abs (timestampdiff( MINUTE, a.timestamp, b.timestamp)) < 5

That will find anything less than 5 minutes apart

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. this gives me a #1582 Incorrect parameter count error, my WHERE statement is now `WHERE a.id != b.id AND 'field' = value AND abs(timestamp diff, MINUTE, a.timestamp, b.timestamp) < 5;`

Comment: Sorry typed it on phone. Fixed now

Comment: Appreciated, it doesn't return anything though.

Comment: Can you get a sql fiddle with an example